# check oil warning light

Tags: commodore

First thing of a morning after i have been driving for about 5 mins the check oil light comes on but only comes on and beeps for 2 seconds then goes off doesn't come on again only happens every few days sometimes  only once a week is this bad or could something be faulty cause the light doesn't stay on.

Comment: First question : have you checked the oil level?

Comment: Based on the beep, I would say this isn't the "check oil" light a.k.a. low oil level light (which is orange / yellow), but rather the oil pressure right (which is red). It is more alarming, but if it's on only for few seconds, it's probably a false alarm. Usually, this light means "stop now! your engine is about to auto-destruct if you continue driving".

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to check the engine oil level on the dipstick. If this is low, top it up to the correct level.

If the engine oil level is ok the fault may just be down to a failing oil pressure switch etc which would require a replacement. An electrical issue is also a possibility which would require investigation.

If the car was low on oil the oil is going somewhere so it's important to have it inspected as the engine oil is likely leaking somewhere. Or if it's a high mileage vehicle the car maybe burning the oil which unfortunately may require rather expensive engine work.

Comment: A semi-blocked oil pickup pipe or failing oil pump would also likely exhibit this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Get your head down the engine bay (after having parked in a safe spot, lifted the handbrake, and left the car in gear if manual or in P if automatic, of course) and see if you have any motor oil leak. Then check the oil level (with a cold engine, the engine off and on flat and level ground) and top up if required (best with the same oil you have inside; otherwise, if you don't know what oil is inside but you know its grade, same oil grade, i.e. if you have a 5W40 inside, top it up with 5W40). If you have no leak, have the oil, and the engine is making no clanking or metallic sound, replace the oil pressure/level switch and clean its electrical connector (they're inexpensive parts and they eventually wear and start leaking oil through the electrical connector). Clean any dirt/oil you see under the engine with a cloth and drive the car around for some time, then check if any oil leak reappears. If you're not leaking any oil and a new pressure switch/level sensor doesn't solve your problem, you have an electrical issue.